# Prove the sequences $\lfloor \alpha n\rfloor $ and $\lfloor \beta n\rfloor $ are disjoint

Tags: arithmetic, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Here is another problem from a problem set that I can't solve.

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be irrational positive numbers such that $\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}=1$
>
> Prove that the sets $\{ \lfloor \alpha n\rfloor | \;n \in \mathbb N \}$ and $\{ \lfloor \beta n\rfloor | \; n \in \mathbb N \}$ are disjoint and their union is $\mathbb N$.

I tried contradiction to prove they're disjoint, but it's a stalemate.

I don't know why any integer have to be of the form $\lfloor \alpha n\rfloor$ or $\lfloor \beta n\rfloor$ ...

Thanks for any hint

Comment: Try to count how many numbers in both sequences together are of size at most $n$.

Comment: Phira's hint is all there is to it. It is a little roundabout way of proving the claim. May be you have not encountered the tactic before?

Comment: This is the famous [Sam Beatty's sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence).

Comment: @i707107 Do you think that this is a good hint?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Nope, never seen this before. Where else does it pop up?

Comment: Yes. The link contains several proof of this.

Comment: @Phira Could you elaborate ?

Comment: @GabrielR. How many of the numbers in the first sequence are smaller than $n$?

Comment: @Phira's hint helps to prove the converse.

Comment: @Phira $\lfloor \frac{n+1}{\alpha} \rfloor +1$ ?

Comment: You can explore these patterns with [this Sage script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjMEKgkAYhO8-xWCX3TLT7RAIQnToFkQ9QPzqryzIqrvrobdv0aK5zQzft8GFyfs3njzNbGp2Ke43qIc2HVSmVJod0-wUnbXxbKn2UcMtqoURVLrJeqFkAud5dKXKEtDsh9c8NuS5vFLvWBYRQiqUIBwgCHvkctlGG7QiDlecoFq3drDQ0AbOkulY5F85doFaVX9UJ4iLwLb9MNhg3kLLX6uWJj9GPT8f&lang=sage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known as Beatty theorem or Rayleigh theorem

1). http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/7968

2) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence

3). https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86516/generalizations-of-the-rayleigh-beatty-theorem

4). http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~fraenkel/Papers/betaW6.pdf

Comment: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~vrusso/papers/Beatty.pdf