# Sequence of floor functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If you write out the multiples of π and take the floor of each term, you get the following sequence: 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 25, 28, etc.

Now, let’s consider the integers that aren’t in this sequence: 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, …

Surprisingly, there also exists a real number t such that the n-th term of this sequence is the floor of  t.n. Find t to the nearest thousandth (3 decimals).
How can I proceed.Thanks in advance.

Comment: sequence is the floor of t.n.  What is t.n. ?

Comment: Product of n and real number t.Like for n=1 , then 3=floor of t.1

Comment: These are Beatty sequences.

Comment: See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793324/prove-the-sequences-lfloor-alpha-n-rfloor-and-lfloor-beta-n-rfloor-are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by others in comment, sequences of the form $a_n = \lfloor \alpha n \rfloor$ is known as [Beatty sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence).

If you are given two irrational numbers $\alpha, \beta > 1$ such that $\frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta} = 1$, the two Beatty sequences $\lfloor \alpha n\rfloor$ and $\lfloor \beta n \rfloor$ will be complementary to each other.
The set of positive integers will be a disjoint union of them:

$$\mathbb{Z}_{+} = \{ \lfloor \alpha n\rfloor : n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \}
\sqcup \{ \lfloor \beta n\rfloor : n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \}$$

For the question at hand, $t$ do exists and equals to  $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{\pi}} = \frac{\pi}{\pi - 1}$.

It is actually not that hard to prove this from first principle.

Let $A = \{ \lfloor \pi n \rfloor : n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \}$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}_{+} \setminus A$. Let $\beta_n$ be the $n^{th}$ member of $B$.

Being the $n^{th}$ positive integer not belongs to $A$, $\beta_n$ satisfies:

$$\#\{ x \in B : x \le \beta_n \} = n \iff \left\lfloor \frac{\beta_n}{\pi}\right\rfloor = \#\{ x \in A : x \le \beta_n \}  = \beta_n - n$$
This leads to

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{\pi}\right)\beta_n + \left\{\frac{\beta_n}{\pi}\right\} = n
\iff
\beta_n + \frac{\pi}{\pi - 1}\left\{\frac{\beta_n}{\pi}\right\}
= \frac{\pi}{\pi - 1}n\\
\implies \beta_n + \left\lfloor\frac{\pi}{\pi - 1}\left\{\frac{\beta_n}{\pi}\right\}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{\pi}{\pi - 1}n \right\rfloor\tag{*1}
$$
Notice $\beta_n \notin A$. For any integer multiple $\pi k$ of $\pi$, whenever
$\pi k \ge \beta_n$, we need to have $\pi k \ge \beta_n+1$. Since $\pi$ is irrational, the inequality is strict. This implies

$$\pi\left(\left\lfloor\frac{\beta_n}{\pi}\right\rfloor + 1 \right) > \beta_n + 1
\iff \pi - 1 > \pi \left\{\frac{\beta_n}{\pi}\right\} 
\implies
 \left\lfloor\frac{\pi}{\pi - 1 }\left\{\frac{\beta_n}{\pi}\right\}\right\rfloor = 0\tag{*2}$$
Combine $(*1)$ and $(*2)$, we obtain
$\displaystyle\;\beta_n = \left\lfloor \frac{\pi}{\pi - 1} n \right\rfloor$ and

$$t = \frac{\pi}{\pi - 1} \approx 1.46694220692426...$$

The desired answer is $1.467$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The equation $\lfloor nt\rfloor=d$ gives you a possible range for $t$ (by $d\le nt<d+1$). The intersection of the ranges for various $n$ will narrow down the interval.