# Integer part of an irrational number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $\alpha,\beta$ irrational positive numbers and the set $A=\{[\alpha n]\mid n\in \mathbb{N^{*}}\}$, respectively $B=\{[\beta m] \mid m\in \mathbb{N^{*}}\}$.

Show that the following statements are equivalent:

1. $ A\cap B = \emptyset $ and $A\cup B =\mathbb{N^*};$
2. $\frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta}=1.$

I know that I have to prove the double equivalent from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 1 and it is easier to start from 2 to 1, but I'm stuck on the part of the integer part of $\alpha n$ and $\beta n$ in each set.
If I bring the fraction to the same denominator we'll get $(\alpha + \beta)/(\alpha \beta)$ but from here I don't know how to proceed, any indication would be appreciated.

Comment: These are called “complementary Beatty sequences”, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/793324/42969

Comment: ... found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clfloor%20%5Calpha%20n%20%5Crfloor%24%2C%20AND%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Calpha%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cbeta%7D%3D1.%24)

Comment: This is a lovely problem, so I urge you to work on it before exploring the links in the question Martin R linked. IMHO, it's probably easier working from part b). Note that one of $\alpha, \beta$ is <2 and the other is >2.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence).

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try that way to see if it helps. Thanks again